# Django forms.ChoiceField to be dynamically created based

Tags: python, django

Im building a website with django where a user could create a shop > choose maximum one of each category > choose multiple products for each category; in that order

I have a DetailView which allows them to see the details of the shop and create a category underneath it.
I`m using FormMixin to allow them create a category, and a ChoiceField for the type of category.

What I want:
Let them choose only from the categories they didnt choose in the past,
eg: I have 3 categories: Woodworks, Food, Tools; if they already have added a Tools category to their shop, they should be able to choose it again (i want the form not display it at all)

My views:

```
class OrganizationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Organization
    queryset = Organization.objects.all().prefetch_related()
    template_name = 'org/org_view.html'
    form_class = CategoryForm


    def test_func(self):
        org = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.profile == org.owned_by:
            return True
        return False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # getting the post to display
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data()

        categories = Category.objects.filter(org=self.object).values_list('cat_name')
        context['categories'] = []
        for category in categories:
            context['categories'].append(*category)

        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.get_object().serializable_value('pk')
        org_id = Organization.objects.get(org_id=pk)
        cat_name = self.request.POST.get('cat_name')
        new_category = Category.objects.create(org=org_id, cat_name=cat_name)

        return self.get(request)
```

My forms.py:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CATEGORIES = ( ('WOOD', 'WoodWorks'), ('FOOD', 'Food'), ('TOOLS', 'Tools') )
    cat_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORIES)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [ 'cat_name' ]
```

Not sure if the models.py is relevent here.

Added models.py for the category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = ( ('WOOD', 'WoodWorks'), ('FOOD', 'Food'), ('TOOLS', 'Tools') )
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORIES)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cat_name} Category'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cat-view', kwargs={'id': self.pk})
```

Comment: First the form shouldn't be a ModelForm for Category since you're not creating or updating a Category, are you? To select from existing categories, use a `ModelChoiceField` and change the queryset to filter the categories you want to show.

Comment: I am creating categories based on the Category model, however the user should be allowed to create as many as he wants as long as is not a duplicate.

Comment: Then you don't want a ChoiceField since that's just a <select> widget, change it to a normal text input field (just remove the custom field in your form, it's already a text input field by default). And you can check for duplicates in the form's clean method, or better, just set `unique=True` on `cat_name` which will automatically check when validating your form.